Ошибка при повторной установке проекта Laravel. Ошибка Каталог "/var/www/lara" не пуст. Как исправить?
Установил Docker, необходимо создать проект на Ларавеле, открыл Windows PowerShell от Администратора, открыл папку внутри папки лежит папка Docker и файлик docker-compose.yml
в терминале ввел команду C:\Project> docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
далее после установки открыл контейнер в Докере PHP- CLI
C:\Project> docker compose exec php-cli bash 

далее внутри контейнера
@d3ed6c168a56:/var/www$ composer create-project laravel/laravel lara

Первая установка Laravel столкнулась с ошибками на 22 процента, запустил заново команду, дошло до 87 процентов тоже завершилось ошибками ,далее пытался установить в другую папку но сразу выдавало ошибку

The process "'/usr/bin/unzip' -qq
'/var/www/lara1/vendor/composer/tmp-50bc29a1915e1901a3db1dbd6b32538b.zip'
-d '/va r/www/lara1/vendor/composer/7531d85b'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

Узнал что нельзя устанавливать проект в разные папки если он некорректно установлен , начал в старую папку ставить и он постоянно выдает ошибку.
Каталог проекта "/var/www/lara" не пустой.
Находил  различные статьи но они не помогали решить проблему что контейнер не пуст. Удалял контейнеры Docker, останавливал, чистил кэш докера.


